# How does es-hadoop (ElasticSearch-Hadoop) do Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hdfs

How does es-hadoop enable Hadoop analytics if it is merely a Hadoop connector to HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to [this project](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop). In which case, the ES Hadoop project has two sides. An ES plugin for HDFS which is used for creating index snapshots. But It also has various utilities that can be used within Mapreduce, Hive, Pig, Spack, ect for interacting with Elasticsearch.

For example, it is possible to bulk load ES documents from HBase using Mapreduce via the ESOutputFileFormat format. It is also possible to use Mapreduce to read from ES by a similar mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

ES is an also analytical tool with a query capacity and visualization tool, kibana. So, with the integration, elasticsearch asserts that you can analyze the data at hdfs using elasticsearch.